# tornado: ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python, tornado

I'm getting this error with tornado:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tornado/curl_httpclient.py", line 480, in _curl_header_callback
    headers.parse_line(header_line)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tornado/httputil.py", line 189, in parse_line
    name, value = line.split(":", 1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I have a list of 100 proxy servers that I'm using to make calls. This happens when making a call using some of those proxies.

```
request = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(url)
request.proxy_host = proxy['host']
request.proxy_port = proxy['port']
HTTP_CLIENT.fetch(request, handle_response)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You didn't say what caused the error..

Comment: @Cong answer updated

Comment: what is `HTTP_CLIENT` ? is it instance of `tornado.httpclient.HTTPClient()` or `tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()` and also tell what is the value of `proxy['host'] ` and `proxy['port']`?

Comment: It's not a Tornado related bug. It's happening because you might be using a proxy server which is running an older version of HTTP. See [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/1451).